# Can PostgreSQL's update the other row on INSERT conflict?

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I have a table which records which is the most recently inserted `b` for the given `a`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS demo (
    id       serial primary key,
    a        int not null,
    b        int not null,
    current  boolean not null
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON demo (a, current) WHERE CURRENT = true;


INSERT INTO demo (a, b, current) VALUES (1, 101, true);
```

I want to be able to insert values and when they conflict, the new row should be updated and the *prior*, conflicting, row should be updated.

E.g. I have

```
select * from demo;
 id | a |  b  | current
----+---+-----+---------
  1 | 1 | 101 | t
```

Then I run something like:

```
INSERT INTO demo (a, b, current)
       VALUES (1, 102, true)
       ON CONFLICT SET «THE OTHER ONE».current = false;
```

and then I would see:

```
select * from demo;
 id | a |  b  | current
----+---+-----+---------
  1 | 1 | 101 | f        <- changed
  2 | 1 | 102 | t
```

Is there syntax in PostgreSQL that allows this?

Comment: Not with `ON CONFLICT`. If for no other reason then the INSERT is going to turn into an UPDATE of the original row. You would need to use a trigger.

Comment: Thanks! The solution doesn't *need* to be `ON CONFLICT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As proposed by @Adrian, you can do it with a trigger :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION before_insert ()
RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
  UPDATE demo
     SET current = false
   WHERE a = NEW.a ;
  RETURN NEW ;
END ;
$$ ;

CREATE TRIGGER before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON demo
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION before_insert () ;
```

see test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bcba1944f7d6d37952c3e4bb4c2dbe13)

PS : the constraint `one_per` will prevent from having several former rows for the same `a` value and with `current = false`

Comment: This is great, thanks. I fixed a bug in my question to allow for multiple `false` values and this works exactly as I'd like.